# Multiple records are created for same order

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am using `Database Transaction` for a endpoint where staff can accept the order perform certain operation thereafter. I don't want same order to be assigned to different staff.I used `Database transaction` for that but the problem is  multiple staff are assigned to same order when the staff accepts the order at same time.
The sample code is provided below:

```
try {
        $message = [
            "status_validation" => "Input status must have value assigned",
            "unique" => "Order is assigned to other driver"
        ];
        $this->validate($request, [
            "restaurant_id" => 'required|integer|min:1',
            "order_id" => 'required|integer|min:1|unique:driver_order,order_id',
            "status" => 'required|status_validation'
        ], $message);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response()->json([
            "status" => "422",
            "message" => $ex->response->original
        ], 422);
    }
    try {

        DB::beginTransaction();
        $assignOrderToDriver = $this->driverOrder->createDriverOrder($request);
        DB:commit();

        return response()->json([
            "status" => "200",
            "message" => "Order has been sucessfully assigned."
        ], 200);
    }
    catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response()->json([
            "status" => "500",
            "message" => $ex->getMessage()
        ], 500);
    }
```

This issue is really creating problem in my project. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Its difficult to understand `$assignOrderToDriver = $this->driverOrder->createDriverOrder($request);` what you did here, you can directly write the code there only rather than calling function, another thing you have written `DB::beginTransaction();` inside try it should be outsise like `DB::beginTransaction(); try{ // success DB::commit()}catch{ DB::rollback();}` like this

Comment: I just  call `createDriverOrder` function for creating order its simply the `Model create()` function. And yeah I did same just you have said but still the issue exists.

Comment: I am not sure but I think it will work if you put the ` $assignOrderToDriver = $this->driverOrder->createDriverOrder($request);` code inside of calling separate function just try it

Comment: I think something should change inside $this->driverOrder->createDriverOrder(). Can you share the code of that function.

Comment: `public function createDriverOrder(array $request)
    {
        return $this->driverOrder->create($request);
    }` this is the code inside the function

Comment: I used transaction lock while creating records. It works for me but my concern is when there are huge number of request will the performance will degrade in terms of speed.